# Adding custom validation to checkout field

Tags: magento2, checkout, validation

With Magento 2 I want to do everything the "clean" way, so without editing any layout files (if possible).

Currently, I am trying to add custom validations to fields at the checkout.

If I create my JS validation rules like [this](https://webkul.com/blog/add-custom-js-validation-rule-magento2/), how do I tell Magento for which fields to use these rules.

Answer (score 0):

In your custom module directory, create a .js file implementing the validator. It should be located under /view/frontend/web/js/model directory.

```
define(
    [],
    function () {
        'use strict';
        return {
            /**
             * Validate something
             *
             * @returns {boolean}
             */
            validate: function() {
                //Put your validation logic here
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Your custom validator must be added to the pool of “additional validators”. To do this, in the /view/frontend/web/js/view directory create a new .js file with the following content:

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
        '<your_module>/js/model/your-validator'
    ],
    function (Component, additionalValidators, yourValidator) {
        'use strict';
        additionalValidators.registerValidator(yourValidator);
        return Component.extend({});
    }
);
```

In your custom module directory, create a new /view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml file. In this file, add the following:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
<referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="additional-payment-validators" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <!-- Declare your validation. START -->
                                                        <item name="your-validator" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">%your_module_dir%/js/view/%your-validation%</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <!-- Declare your validation. END -->
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: So, which part of this answers my question? Where exactly do I specify the field the validation form should be used for?

Comment: 'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators'

Comment: this code place after or below your element <item name="your-validator" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">%your_module_dir%/js/view/%your-validation%</item>
                                                        </item>

Comment: @BirjitsinhZala, How can I show a custom message from the validate: function ?

Comment: afaik this approach works only for popup messages and only for "place order" button. And in this example there are no option how to check field on the fly.

Comment: @Anthony is correct, its only works for step 2, do you guys know any way to create custom validate on step 1 (Shipping Address)?

Comment: I've follow devdoc and mageplaza, but still cant validate at first step
 https://www.mageplaza.com/custom-shipping-carrier-validator-magento-2.html
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_carrier.html
Here is my custom checkout module btw
https://github.com/saxsax1995/MagentoCheckoutCustom

Comment: Hi @BirjitsinhZala How to define namespace of validator in function ? yourValidator

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link can help you: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_order.html

Answer (score 0):

You must add the validation js file under "shipping-rates-validation" array in checkout_index_index.xml file like below to work on the checkout shipping form.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="step-config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shipping-rates-validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="<your-validation-name>" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">%your_module%/js/view/%your-validation%</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```