# Magento2: Set PO box validation on checkout page in shipping address in street field

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address

How to set PO box validation on checkout page in shipping address in street field.

[image]

If anyone enter string like PO Box, P.O Box, Post Office Box.
So want throw java script error.

Comment: You need the js regex or you want to know how to add it?

Comment: I want just validate first field of the Street Address. Like this https://www.improvboy.com/magento-articles/no-po-box-for-shipping-in-magento-1-9-checkout/, But in Magento2

Comment: At least that article gave you the regex. See here how to do it in Magento2 https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/210569/3024

Comment: did you find any solution?